# Running my own email server?

Tags: server, email, gmail

I’ve seen this question asked in various forums but curious if things have changed over time.

**QUESTION**: I’d like to run my own mail server to fully own all of my data but worried about two things. (1) Spam and (2) high availability.

**POTENTIAL SOLUTION**: I thought about continuing to use GMAIL to take advantage of their SPAM/availability services. Then just have my server pull mail every 5 minute and delete on the GMAIL server once its’s pulled the message down.  Same process on the outbound messages, send and delete from sent messages.  This seems over engineered which leads to:

**POTENTIAL SOLUTION 2**: Run my own server but utilize some service for SPAM filtering?  I know the enterprise has products like mimecast and proofpoint that will perform the spam filtering and also queue up messages if your server goes down.  Does anything exist like this for individuals (not enterprise).

Any other solutions that make a lot more sense?  Appreciate all your insight on this.

Brian

Comment: Generally it is more trouble than it’s worth to run your own mail server. You’ll find that most recipients will block your messages or mark them as spam immediately, warranting using GMail (or a similar service) to route sent messages. Then, if you’re using a service to route both sent and received messages, you’ll wonder why you do it at all 

Comment: If your ISP doesn't care about their address reputation, then you can forget running a mail server with them (they'll be in all sorts of RBLs forever in most cases). But if you choose a high quality ISP (usually small, not very cheap but run by people who have actual knowledge and experience) it's perfectly OK. I've run my own (sending only about 200-500 mails a day though) for almost 25 years with hardly any significant issues.